# storyboard IB to big for simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, swift

i've created a tableView using the storyboard, but it seems like the storyboard is to big in relation to the simulator (iphone 5s). What is the reason for this? and how can i solve this?

## Storyboard

[image]

## simulator (iphone 5s)

[image]

Comment: Auto Layout - Size Classes. Search for it. You will find answer.

Comment: Look into AutoLayout.  Storyboard makes it dead easy to implement UI designs that scale based on the size of the viewport. Here's an article on implementing AutoLayout in IB: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_auto_layout/chapters/pin-constraints.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014226-CH28-SW1